# How to run PhantomJS in client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, npm, phantomjs

I am using a [HTML to PDF converter that uses phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) and the way to use it is like this:

```
npm install -g html-pdf

var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
});
```

And running it in the command-line like `html-pdf test/businesscard.html businesscard.pdf`

Now my problem is that, what if I want to use it in client that instead of typing through the command-line, I can use it with a button or something like that.

I already tried it but I am getting missing modules like `child_process` and `fs(webpack problem but fixed)`.

Is there a way to do this in client side?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this in client side?

Depends on your definition of a client. If you mean a browser then no, not possible*. If your business process allows to create and distribute a stand-alone desktop application then yes, possible.

> I can use it with a button or something like that.

You can use a framework for building desktop applications like [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) or [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/). Being essentially node.js applications they allow for using any node modules plus the benefit of simple GUI construction with HTML and CSS.

---

* Still there's a way to kinda do it in a browser - turning this into a webservice. You could have a webpage with a button that triggers a server-side script that launches html-pdf script.

Comment: "You could have a webpage with a button that triggers a server-side script that launches html-pdf script." You mean a code that will run a shell script?